# Can a webform list who has already signed up for an event?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I would like to use a webform for people to signup for an event - but they need to see who else has signed up as these events need at least one of each gender. The event is a kind of 'first aid' event where you must have both men and women on duty - not just all men or all women.  I've used webforms for signing up individuals for events, but not run into this requirement before.

Answer (score 4):

You can list the people using CiviCRM Views and add the View to the same page as the webform.  Easiest is to put the View into a block, but you can also do this with the Paragraphs module or Panels.

Comment: Thanks Jon - how do I restrict the view of the participants to the event that the user has selected?  i.e. the user may be scrolling through several events & of course I just want show who's signed up for each currently selected event - (maybe this is a separate question!)

Comment: If you have a small number of events, you can simply have multiple display views and assign them manually.  If you have a larger number, you're going to need to use the "contextual filter" feature.  The trick is telling the contextual filter the event ID.  Is there a change the event ID is in the URL or can be added to it?

Answer (score 3):

Create a link and point potential registrants to the standard CiviCRM public participant listing -

https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/participant?reset=1&id=3

Where id=3 is the event ID.

There’s a participant listing option in the events info and settings section -

To allow users to see a listing of participants, set this field to 'Name' (list names only), 'Name and Email', or 'Name, Status and Register Date'. You will need to set Access Control permissions to include 'view event participants' for any Roles you want to access this listing.

[image: Public participant listing option]

[image: Link to public participant listing]

Comment: Thanks, but what I need to see is name, role and gender so the View solution below is probably what I need.